# How to select all <pre> which contain only one line?

Tags: jquery, css

`$('pre:contains("\n")')` will select all `<pre>` which contain at least one newline.
How to select all `<pre>` which contains no newline or only one newline at the end?
What's the quick way?

#### match

```
<pre>A</pre>
```

---

```
<pre>B
</pre>
```

#### not match

```
<pre>C

</pre>
```

---

```
<pre>

D</pre>
```

---

```
<pre>

E
</pre>
```

Comment: `$('pre:not(:contains("\n"))')` will select those without `\n`. Not sure about the one with only an `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps simple approach would suffice, trimmed the text then detect newline:

```
var myList = $('pre').filter(function(index) {
    var val = $(this).text().trim();
    return val.indexOf('\n') == -1;
});

$.each(myList, function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});​
```

Sample data:

```
<pre>hello</pre>

<pre>great
</pre>

<pre>you
say
</pre>

<pre>

yes</pre>

<pre>

heila
</pre>

<pre>not
included</pre>

<pre>included</pre>
​
```

Outputs:

```
 hello
 great
 yes
 heila
 included
```

Live test: http://jsfiddle.net/Anb6q/1/

Comment: one-liner: `$('pre').filter(function(){return $(this).text().trim().indexOf('\n')==-1})`

Comment: yep, one-liner is good. but when posting answers on stackoverflow, which has limited text area; i tend to wrap lines, so SOers don't need to scroll the answer horizontally to see the complete code

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

`$('pre:not(:contains("\n"))')`

Comment: This statement matches only the first `pre`

Answer (score 1):

```
var myList = $('pre').filter(function(index) {
    var val = $(this).text();
    return val.substring(0, val.length -2).indexOf('\n') === -1;
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/szh94/2/)...

Edited [Michael Buen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11432/michael-buen) remark

Comment: "This statement matches only the first pre – mamoo" <-- and then your code(took a look on your jsFiddle code) fails on the first pre ;-)  I include clear data(i.e. no duplicate, to prevent confusion), the first hello didn't appear on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/szh94/1/

Comment: @kev because a newline as last character is acceptable, thus we ignore the last character during the check...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get.

```
$('pre').filter(function(){
    var txt = $(this).text()
    return txt.substring(0, txt.length-1).indexOf('\n')==-1
}).css({'background-color':'#FFF4E8',
        'border-top':'1px solid #FF6600',
        'border-bottom':'1px solid #FF6600',
        'padding': '1px 0 1px 0',
})
```